# MS Access Pass-Through DSN-less query: what is wrong with my connection string?

Tags: sql, string, connection

I've done this before and am following my own example but it's not working.  I have a simple pass-through query in MS Access 2013.  It is supposed to query (just a "SELECT * from " query for now) a Microsoft SQL Server using a DNS-less connection string.  The server is set up for mixed authentication.  I can use the Linked Table Manager and open tables from this same MS Access file.  I can ping the servername from a command prompt.  The client computer is Windows 7 and has the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client installed. I suspect something's up with my connection string, but I can't see it.

In the "ODBC Connect Str" property of my Pass-Through query I have:

`ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=<dbname>`

When I try and View the query I get

ODBC--connection to 'SQL ServerSERVERNAME' failed.

EDIT: Yes, I have tables linked to the same SQL server via Linked Table Manager.  I also have an ODBC connection to the same server, and it tests just fine (using the "Test Connection" button in the ODBC connection wizard.

Yes, my suspicion is that it's something to do with the connection string.  I just don't see the problem and am hoping someone has a better eye than I do, or has some experience with this that will help produce an idea.

The server is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 running on Windows Server 2016.

I'm hoping my edits can cause this question to be unlocked again.

See my comment below for tips and my ultimate answer, in case you are struggling with this also.

Comment: So, you can use Linked Table Manager and open the tables on that same SQL Server just fine? What if you create an ODBC connection (not within Access but literally Windows ODBC) and input the same info using Windows Auth to that db? If the connection is successful, it's def something with your string. Is this server a different version? Do you have access to the SQL Server error log to confirm whether the request even made it to the server? [This site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/) has different strings based on your destination server version, which you didn't include.

Comment: Yes, I have tables linked to the same SQL server via Linked Table Manager. I also have an ODBC connection to the same server, and it tests just fine (using the "Test Connection" button in the ODBC connection wizard.  I will look at the site you linked.  Thanks.

Comment: I made these two changes:  I chaged the "Yes" to "True" for "Trusted_Connection".  I then added the "Integrated Parameter = True" option.  Now the connection string works.